# For UITableView in UITableCellView method cellForRowAtIndexPath not called, but numberOfRowsInSection called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface, autolayout

I am working on a existing project.
The project has one screen where details of an orders are displayed.
Every order has order items. So, naturally a table view is used to display order items. This works fine.
Now, the system has been extended in that way that every order item can have 0 or more toppings. If there are toppings for order item, they also need to shown in a list.
So, the approach I took is to try and implement a table view which will be responsible for showing order item toppings inside order item cell.
I've read about this approach and people say that it is possible.

The problem I have now is that for toppings table view in order item table view cell, the `numberOfRowsInSection` method is called, however the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called at all.

I have read about this issue and the people say that is has to do with table view frame not being set correctly.

I've setup the order item with toppings cell in `Interface Builder` with `AutoLayout`.
I (think) all the constraints are in place in order for cell to render it's content and height correctly.
However, from the screenshots it can be seen that the toppings `tableview` is not rendered at all.

Anybody has an idea of what might cause the table with not to render?
Any help, thoughts, comments are appreciated. Thank you.
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check whether noOfRowsInSection method returns 0 then cellForRowAtIndexPath method won't call.Please don't post code as image put directly as code.

Comment: Show code for your UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate

Comment: noOfRowsInSection method returns the correct number of rows, which is in my case 1. See attached console output.

Comment: `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` should return a constant value not `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to with your `UITableViewDelegate` and the way you want to achieve automatic height for your cells.

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, which actually is equal to `-1.0`. If you look at [that function's description in documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc) you will see

> **Return Value**
>   A nonnegative floating-point value that specifies the height (in points) that row should be.

Now, if each of your rows have negative height, then the table view has nothing to display - hence `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called.

**TL,DR**
You were almost there - `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` should be set to `UITableView.rowHeight`, not returned in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

```
toppingsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Also, remove the functions `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll try this and let you know how it goes. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi @mag_zbc, I have managed to solve the issue in the end. The comment you have posted helped me guide in the right direction. However, I could not make it work with automatic dimension, so I've made it work by calculating the height of the cell with table view manually. Seems to do the job for now. Thanks for you swift help.